# Antlr: How to match letters that are not CJK letters?

Tags: java, parsing, unicode, antlr, antlr4

I'd like to match words that consist of Unicode letters, except for CJK (Chinese-Japanese-Korean) characters. CJK characters should get recognized separately and individually. A Unicode letter is any character where the Java Character.isLetter(ch) is true.

How do I recognize every character which is a letter and not CJK? In JFlex, I did this:

```
cjk=[\u4E00-\u9FCF]|[\u3400-\u4DBF]|...

/* this translates to ([:letter:] and (not {cjk})) */
letter=!(![:letter:] | {cjk})

word=letter+
```

This syntax doesn't work in Antlr. I know that I can use the following code to recognize a letter, but I don't know how to exclude CJK.

```
LETTER :    [\p{L}];
```

Comment: Since you seem to already be using one token per letter, you can leverage [how the lexer works](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201708242248072432284) by declaring a `CJK` lexer rule *above* your `LETTER` rule, and then just use `LETTER: [\p{L}];`.

Comment: No, I'm grouping non-CJK letters into words, and the longest-match rule defeats this trick.

Comment: I see, then `LETTER` should be a fragment I guess. You may try the double negation trick like you did in JFlex: `fragment LETTER: ~[\P{L}<insert cjk ranges here>];`, or just use a predicate `fragment LETTER: [\p{L}] { java code that returns a bool }?;` although this will most probably impact lexing performance.

Comment: I tried the negation trick both with and without making LETTER (and CJK) a fragment. Either way I get error "rule reference CJK is not currently supported in a set". Semantic predicate would probably work (slowly).

Comment: You'd have to inline the `CJK` rule, you can't include it in a character set like the error says.